# Is this proof on closed sets correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I am not exactly sure if my proof is correct. Please excuse my bad english language skills since I am not a native speaker. Please correct me, if necessary, on both my mathematical skills and my language abilities.
Let´s start with the proof.

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Furthermore let $A \subseteq X$ be closed and $B \subseteq A $ be closed in $A$, then $B$ is closed in $X$.

Proof:

Let $x \in X \setminus B$ be abritary. Then $x \in X$ and $x \notin B$. Suppose $x \in A$. Then $x \in A \setminus B$. Since $B$ is closed in $A$ this means $x$ has to be an interior point and we are done. So let $x \notin A$. Then $x$ has to be an element of $X \setminus A$. Since $A$ is closed in $X$ this means $X \setminus A$ has to be an open set as well. So $x$ has to be an interior point. Since $x \in X \setminus B$ was abritary and every case has been exhausted this shows that every point $x \in X \setminus B$ has to be an interior point, thus $X\setminus B$ is an open set, thus $B$ has to be closed in $X$ by definition.

q. e. d?

This seems to be a little too easy for my taste, but I do not know what could have gone wrong. I would love someone to give me advice if needed. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I haven't had gone through the proof itself yet, but aside from three small mistakes ("little **to** easy", "but **i** do not know", and "an open set **aswell**"), all of which native speakers continuously make, your English is perfect. Without the disclaimer at the start, I would have assumed you were a native speaker. Well done.

Comment: You start your proof by saying if $B$ is closed in $X$, which is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @Duncan Ramage the mistake have been corrected thanks for the nice words

Comment: @Benji Altman I have deleted the flawed line but is the argument correct?

Comment: @MathNewbie We know that $A\setminus B$ is open in $A$, but do we know that it is open in $X$?

Comment: @MathNewbie $A$ is closed in $X$, unless you have a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest this answer **If** you've learned the definitions of the subset topology; this could be made very simple:

$B$ is closed in $A$, so $B = A\cap C$ for $C$ closed in $X$.

$A$ is closed in $X$ implies that $B$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much. But is my proof a blunder?

Comment: @MathNewbie yes IMO :)

Comment: could you tell me why?

Comment: @MathNewbie for one thing I don't follow your first implication, $x$ is an interior point (you should also specify of what).

Comment: I am so stuck right now. Can the "proof" be corrected or is it flawed all the way?

Comment: @MathNewbie don't feel helpless - this is how learning should be. Go back to the definitions and rethink. If you're feeling anxious, try again tomorrow. There are several ways to prove what you want. One is direct, proving that $B$ is closed (consider sequences, as we're in a metric space). Another is showing that $X -B$ is open, which may be easier. Another is what I've shown. I suggest starting over - sometimes we make false assumptions and those are very hard to overcome when we're trying to correct an attempt that feels lost. Let me know if I can help further..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my answer is correct, but I would try:

$B \subseteq X$ is closed in $X$ iff it contains all its limit points, which means we have to show that for every convergent sequence $b_n \subseteq B$ $$b_n \rightarrow x \in X  :  \ x \in B$$

Since $A$ is closed in $X$ and $b_n \subseteq B \subseteq A$ : $ \ x \in A$

Since $B$ is closed in $A$ and $b_n \rightarrow x \in A \subseteq X$ : $ \ x \in B$

which is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the nice advices you guys have given me. I am a little burned out at the moment since I have been struggling quite a bit recently. I think it is because I have overdone it by working until midnight to finish my assignments thus I am getting a bit impatient. Thanks again. It is good to know that there is a community of skilled members in this forum to whom I can turn and ask for advice if I am stuck.